# Make longitude, latitude and elevation data points into grid (R)

Tags: r, geospatial, latitude-longitude, shapefile, r-grid

I am trying to create grids from longitude, latitude and elevation data points but I am having a lot of difficulty. Here is more details.

I have longitude, latitude and elevation data points that looks as fallow when plotted for different elevation:

[image]

My ultimate goal would be to create a grid for each of the previous shapes and use the grids into some kriging coding.

I read over a bunch of documentation but I can't quite figure out how to do that. I thought I maybe had to create a shapefile from the longitude, latitude and elevation and from there creates grid, but still I can figure out how to do this as well.

Anything would help, especially some coding example that acheive such thing!

Thanks. (Here is the code for the previous graph)

```
all_pit_data<- read.table("ALL_PIT_DATA.csv",header=TRUE,sep=",")
library(ggplot2)
all_pit_data$intervals <- cut_interval(all_pit_data$z1, n=9)

windows()
ggplot(all_pit_data, aes(x = x1, y = y1, color = z1)) + 
  geom_point(shape=1) + 
  facet_wrap ( ~ intervals, nrow=3) +
  labs(x = "x", y = "y", colour = "Depth")enter code here
```

Comment: Perhaps  `akima::interp` will help -- it does 2-D interpolation to place data values onto a regularly spaced grid.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I have sucessfully interpolated a surface and made a grid with `akima::interp`. However, I have not been able to create a surface for each layer and also, I have not been able to code a grid that has the surface shape (as previously shown) as it keep a reactangular shape (the whole x and y range).